# serious problems with the double factorial of a defined function

Tags: function-construction

I have calculations involving the following sum:

```
Sum[Co f[2n]!! Cos[2(n-l)p] {n, 1, ∞}, {l, 0, n - 1}]
```

where

`co=( Sum[ Factorial[2 n] Abs[v]^2n  (f[2n]!!)^2 /(2^n Factorial[n])^2]`  )^(-1/2)

```
f[2n]!! = f[0] f[2] f[4], ..., f[2n]
```

with `f[0] = 1`. In my case

```
f[n_] := LaguerreL}[n, 1, x^2]/((n + 1) LaguerreL[n, 0, x^2])
```

I am having a lot of difficulty expressing the expression `f[n]!!` in *Mathematica*. I am looking for ideas on how to make the expression.

Comment: `factorial2f[n_] := Product[f[k], {k, 0, n, 2}];`

Answer (score 0):

$x$ should probably be a variable too. Let $g$ be your double factorial:

```
f[n_, x_] := LaguerreL[n, 1, x]/((n + 1) LaguerreL[n, 0, x]); 
g[n_, x_] := Product[f[2 k, x], {k, 0, n}];
```

Comment: thank you, but my results still do not matches with those reported by use of above function